# Android video recording

Tags: android, video-capture

hi
i have changed my code as below but the problem now is ,the recording wont stop at 2 minutes in samsung galaxy.ohters fine

```
Intent i = new Intent("android.media.action.VIDEO_CAPTURE");
                                i
                                        .putExtra(
                                                android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
                                                Uri.fromFile(videofile));
                                i
                                        .putExtra(
                                                android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY,
                                                0);
                                i.putExtra("android.intent.extra.durationLimit", 120); 
                                startActivityForResult(i, 2);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it works on other devices my guess would be that the Samsung camera app doesn't understand/handles that option passed to the activity.

Answer (score 0):

android.intent.extra.durationLimit is available in 2.2/API8/Froyo.

From http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.html#EXTRA_DURATION_LIMIT

public static final String EXTRA_DURATION_LIMIT       Since: API Level 8

I think most Samsung Galaxy devices were released with 2.1/Eclair and some have recently been upgraded to 2.2/Froyo.